# PHPExcel format column to date format 14-Mar

Tags: php, phpexcel

Is it possible to format a column (C2:C50) with PHPExcel with the following selected values:

[image: Excel date format (14-Mar)]

I really can't get this to work.. 
Already tried something like:

```
$sheet->getStyle('C2:C50')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DMMINUS);
```

But when I look a the cell properties it said the cell is formatted like:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

PHPExcel only has a limited set of built-in constants for formats, but you can set the format code to any valid (custom) format just by using the appropriate string:

```
$sheet->getStyle('C2:C50')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('d-mmm');
```

Note that locale-specific day/month names such as `Woensdaag` and `Maart` aren't supported by writers other than the MS Excel specific writers (ie. not in CSV, HTML, PDF)

Most custom format strings will work, though there are a few obscure ones such as `$#,," M"` that aren't directly supported, for display in formats other than MS Excel itself

Comment: Thank you for your quick reaction! The thing is: I use PHPExcel to create a daily export from a PHP application and that export file needs to be imported (copy/paste) into a large existing Excel document where the date is formatted like I mentioned. When I now copy the content from that export file into that large excel document, everything seems to be formatted as it should be, except for the date field.. Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Does the file that is created by PHPExcel show the date in the correct format for the defined mask? Is it the cut-and-paste that's causing the problems?

Comment: No, it's just the opposite.. The PHPExcel file says something like: 10-10 and the column in that large excel file is formatted as date -> 10-Oct. When I just type 10-10 in that large document, the file format the input automatic like 10-Oct. But when I copy/paste from my export file it doesn't and the input stays like 10-10..

Comment: Well a format mask of 'dd-mm' (or 'd-m', which is what PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DMMINUS gives you) will display 10th October as `10-10`; a format mask of 'dd-mmm' will display 10th October as `10-Oct`. When you cut-and-paste from one excel workbook into another with MS Excel, then existing formatting codes will be retained