# How to change a date to a General/numeric format number using PHP?

Tags: php

How can I convert today's date (m,d,Y) to a number (like in Excel). eg; today (2/21/2014) to Excel number (41690). I know how to get today's date, but don't know how to convert it.

Thanks

Comment: There is no relationship between that date and that number

Comment: Might be because it's late in the evening, but I don't see how 2/21/2014 maps to 41690, could you shed some light on this ?

Comment: @SirDarius, JohnConde He's not crazy... lol, in Excel dates are stored as days passed since 1900-Jan-0.

Comment: Take look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270785/phpexcel-format-column-to-date-format-14-mar

Comment: @JohnConde There is. Excel is just using a really strange format to store dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Excel number value for the date represents the [number of days since 01/01/1900](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/datevalue-HP005209044.aspx).

So, you should use the following code (assuming GMT):

```
$today = '2014-02-21';

$datetime1 = new DateTime($today);
$datetime2 = new DateTime('1900-01-01');

$interval = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);
$excelDate = $interval->days + 1;

print "$today in Excel is: $excelDate";
```

Comment: Why the `+3`? Also, this prints `41691` instead of `41690`. See here: http://3v4l.org/seeDK

Comment: For improved performance, you could hardcode the timestamp of `1900-01-01` and substract it from `time()`, then divide by `(60*60*24)` and round down.

Comment: @Carsten: It should output `41691` as `41691` is `2014-02-21` in Excel. `41690` is `2014-02-20`. It is `+3` because the counting starts from `1900-01-00` (and not from `1900-01-01`)

Comment: @Carsten Enter this in Excel: `=DATEVALUE("2014-02-21")`  It'll give you `41691`.

Comment: @Razvan Shouldn't it be `+ 1`?  Why is it `+ 2`?  Difference between those dates is `41690` days, so you should only have to add `1`.

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out myself right now. For some reason it doesn't work with `+1` for `2014-02-21` but it works fine for earlier dates (such as `1900-01-10`).

Comment: This was due to timezones - `+1` works fine with GMT.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try [`time()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function which generates UNIX timestamp. You can convert the timestamp back to readable format using [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$today=date('Y-m-d');// today;
$ts = strtotime($today); // today to seconds after 1970-01-01 (UNIX hour)
echo floor((($ts)/3600)/24)+25569;  // 25569 is the difference in second from 1970 to 1900
?>
```