# Read Excel's internal calculated values with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, xlsx

I'm using PHPExcel library to read Microsoft Office Excel xlsx files. My xlsx has only one row:

[image]

As I tried xlsx is simply a zip file which contains xml files. I unzipped my xlsx file

```
:~> unzip w2.xlsx -d w2
Archive:  w2.xlsx
  inflating: w2/_rels/.rels
  inflating: w2/docProps/app.xml
  inflating: w2/docProps/core.xml
  inflating: w2/xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels
  inflating: w2/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
  inflating: w2/xl/styles.xml
  inflating: w2/xl/workbook.xml
  inflating: w2/[Content_Types].xml
```

and opened w2/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml which contains next xml (important part displayed below):

```
<sheetData>
  <row collapsed="false" customFormat="false" customHeight="false" hidden="false"  ht="12.1" outlineLevel="0" r="1">
    <c r="A1" s="1" t="n">
      <f aca="true">RAND()*10000/100</f>
      <v>94.5569227915257</v>
    </c>
    <c r="C1" s="1"/>
  </row>
</sheetData>
```

It seems that Excel internally stores already calculated value. Does a PHPExcel library has some method to read this internally calculated value. I know there are methods like getValue (returns formula =RAND*10000/1000), getCalculatedValue (calculates value), getFormattedValue (also calculates value)

Comment: I found method getOldCalculatedValue() in file Cell.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPExcel does indeed have a method to retrieve that value for any cell:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getOldCalculatedValue();
```

Note that this is not guaranteed.... if automatic calculation has been disabled in MS Excel, then it will only be as valid as the the last time that MS Excel actually executed the calculation

Answer (score 0):

Its about the cell-format. If it is the general "number" excel will show up 8 decimal places. You can set up a custom format for each cell in phpexcel like this.

```
$sheet->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('0.0000000000');
```

Im not fully sure if the format (writing down O's) is correct, cant try it out for the moment.
Try to get the value after setting the custom format with **getCalculatedValue**.

Credits: [user2131419 / so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270785/phpexcel-format-column-to-date-format-14-mar)

**Edit:**
Hah*. As long as mr baker turns into this you can ignore my post. His answer is obviously the most correct one, as always. :)

Comment: The subject here is cell's calculated value, I mean the value that Excel already calculated. Although thanks for pointing setFormatCode, maybe it will come handy someday.

Comment: I know!? Where's the problem? I guess phpexcel will get the calulated value according to its formula AND format. If you change the format first and then get the calculated value it should work. That was everything I tried pointing to. :)

Comment: The problem here is that I want to read values instead of formulas to provide consistency between PHP and Excel. For example, PHP could calculates value different than Excel for unknown reason (rounding may be different, internal representation ..., PHP 5.6 does things different than PHP 5.2 or something). If there is a way to read already calculated Excel values, this way we get the values as Excel calculated and not PHP.

Comment: Are you sure you havnt misunderstood my posts? Cant see a point we are talking about different things here. But anyway, the solution is already found, need to turn back to my own work. Happy coding dude.